# Return the row number if value is between two values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a lookup table with a range of number (Min and Max) in two columns. ON the second sheet, it contains the numbers (1-100). And I'd like to lookup the row number from the lookup table. How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$11,MATCH(D2,B$2:B$11,1))
```

[image]

Comment: That actually works well, even though it is only based on column B, and column C is not taken into consideration. Just be aware of this, if you have gaps in the data, this will not work!

Also, ensure that the matching range (`B$2:B$11` in this example) is sorted in increasing order. As the documentation states:

"The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending order, for example: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE."

Comment: @CedricMeury  Thank you...the limitations you mention are valid ... I will update this post later...thanks again !

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that Band is in the A-Column, Min in the B-Column and so on and the headers in the first row, put this in F2 and drag down as necessary:

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(1,(E2<=$C$2:$C$11)*(E2>=$B$2:$B$11),0))}
```

Please note that you don't have to put in the `{}`, this indicates, that this is a array formula, so you have to enter this formula with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of just `Enter`.

If you have the data in different ranges, then you will have to adjust the ranges accordingly.

If you are interested in the row instead of the Band, then wrap `ROW` arround the formula, so:

```
{=ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(1,(E2<=$C$2:$C$11)*(E2>=$B$2:$B$11),0)))}
```

Again with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Comment: Great answer, the most voted one assumes excluding-ordered intervals

Answer (score 0):

You can use index match.

- Give the lookup table a name, for example "tbl"
- Lets say numbers are in column G

Then you can use this formula:
=INDEX(tbl[band];MATCH(1;(G11>=tbl[min]) * (G11 < tbl[max]);0))

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpWo7.png)
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZyPm.png)

Reference:https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria